# Conditional Independence with infinite r.v.'s

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I read this property in "Probability with Martingales" from Williams(page 91-92):

> Suppose that $X_1 , ...,X_r $ are independent, each $X_k$ with law $\lambda_k$. If $h$ is bounded and $\mathcal{B}^r $-measurable ; and we define for $x_1 \in \mathbb{R} $ :
>   $$ \gamma^h(x_1):=\mathbb{E}(h(x_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_r)) $$
>   then $\gamma^h(X_1) $ is a version of the conditional expectation
>   $$\mathbb{E}(h(X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_r)|X_1) $$

I need to figure out if the property holds when I have infinite R.V.'s $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \ $  instead of   $\  r  $ R.V.'s ; and I condition on, say, $(X_N)_{N\in \mathbb{N}}$.

The proof for the property in the finite case uses Fubbini's Theorem; but I understand that it holds only for finite product measures.

Comment: Both statements are special cases of the fact that $E(h(\xi,\eta)\mid\xi)=k(\xi)$ where $k(x)=E(h(x,\eta))$ for every $x$ in $E$, for every independent random variables $\xi:(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)\to(E,\mathcal E)$ and $\eta:(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)\to(G,\mathcal G)$ and every bounded measurable function $h:(E\times G,\mathcal E\otimes\mathcal G)\to(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

Comment: Thank you, do you know any bibliography where I can read this generalized property('s proof) ? Or is it just Fubbini "remodeled" ? 
Still I would like to read it thouroughly , I would appreciate bibliography very much

Comment: @Max Lemma 6.2.1. (p236) in https://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf